# How to binding right and left ctrl keys separately in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I reassigned `left ctrl` key to `capslock` key to use ctrl in Emacs.

Is there a way to bind right and left ctrl keys separately?

For example, I want to bind `left-ctrl-a` to `select all` and `right-ctrl-a` to `beginning-of-line`. In other words, I want to emulate `ctrl` and `command` key concept of OS X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's just one `control` modifier supported in X11:

```
$ xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 5 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Hyper_L (0x42),  Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

As you can see, although there are seperate key symbols for left and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, both of them are bound to the same modifier, `control`.  You could however bind your `Ctrl_L` to another modifier, not used elsewhere (in the above example, this could be `mod3`, for example) and configure your Emacs to use `C-a` (which would be your *right* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) as usual (`beginning-of-line`) but tell it to handle `Mod3-a` (your *left* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) as you prefer.